# How to parse SOAP xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, soap

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:chec="http://www.eds.com/AirlineSOASchema/CheckIn/" xmlns:air="http://www.eds.com/AirlineSOASchema/AirCheckInRQ" xmlns:com="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/CommonTypes" xmlns:com1="http://www.eds.com/AirlineSOASchema/AirCommonTypes" xmlns:air1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/AirCommonTypes">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <chec:checkIn>
         <air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ Version="4.000">
            <air:POS>
               <com:Source AirlineVendorID="CM"/>
            </air:POS>
            <air:MessageFunction Function="CheckIn"/>
            <air:FlightInfo RPH="1">
               <com1:CarrierInfo Code="CM" FlightNumber="360"/>
               <com1:DepartureInformation DateOfDeparture="2020-10-29T00:00:00" LocationCode="PTY"/>
            </air:FlightInfo>
            <air:PassengerInfo RPH="1" GivenNameRefNumber="1" SurnameRefNumber="1">
               <com1:PassengerName>
                  <com:GivenName>DARREN</com:GivenName>
                  <com:Surname>STEVENS</com:Surname>
               </com1:PassengerName>
               <com1:PassengerType />
            </air:PassengerInfo>
            <air:PassengerFlightInfo PassengerRPH="1" FlightRPH="1">
               <com1:SeatBoardingInfo SeatNumber="21C"/>
            </air:PassengerFlightInfo>
            <air:BaggageInfo PassengerRPH="1" CheckedBagCountTotal="0">
            </air:BaggageInfo>
         </air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ>
      </chec:checkIn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

mytree = ET.parse('check_in.xml')

## It will give me the root element of xml which i parse

myroot = mytree.getroot()
print(myroot)
print(myroot.tag)
`

This is a SOAP XML and I want to parse it in python.

Comment: what is the info you want to extract from the xml?

Comment: Make use of beautifulsoup for the same. You can find example: https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/

Comment: This is SOAP XML so I find difficult? If have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
xml = utils.getFileContent('test.xml')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
nodes = doc.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ').children
print (nodes.tag)

print (doc.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ')['Version'])
print (doc.select('com:Source'))
```

Result:

```
['air:POS', 'air:MessageFunction', 'air:FlightInfo', 'air:PassengerInfo', 'air:PassengerFlightInfo', 'air:BaggageInfo']
4.000
{'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
```

Put all the tag in the loop.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

def loop(node):
  print ([(k,v) for k,v in node.items() if k!='html']) # edited
  children = node.children
  if children:
    for c in children:
      loop(c)
  else:
    print ('tag, value: ', node.tag,',', node.text)

doc = SimplifiedDoc(utils.getFileContent('test.xml'))
loop(doc.select('soapenv:Envelope'))
```

Loop EDS_AirCheckInRQ

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
doc = SimplifiedDoc(utils.getFileContent('test.xml'))
lstEDS_AirCheckInRQ = doc.selects('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ')

for EDS_AirCheckInRQ in lstEDS_AirCheckInRQ:
   print (EDS_AirCheckInRQ['Version'])
   print (EDS_AirCheckInRQ.select('com:Source')['AirlineVendorID'])
   print (EDS_AirCheckInRQ.select('air:MessageFunction')['Function'])
```

[Here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples) are more examples. This lib is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, the above code is working fine for me. If anyone have any idea what is the use of smiplifiedDoc ?

Comment: @MinhajKhan It is a library for parsing data such as XML and HTML.

Comment: simplified_scrapy it is a framework for extracting data right?

Comment: can I select multiple nodes and print the data?

Comment: @MinhajKhan Of course, try this: doc.selects('tag')

Comment: yes, I can print multiple values using tag and print statement multiple times. Is there any way to put all the tag in the loop and print it once?

Comment: @MinhajKhan I updated the answer to see if it is what you want.

Comment: It only prints tags present in XML the value within is not printing?

Comment: @MinhajKhan I modified one line: print ([(k,v) for k,v in node.items() if k!='html'])

Comment: @MinhajKhan I updated the answer. Maybe it can help you.