# How to register XML namespace with prefix ns2

Tags: python, xml, soap, elementtree, xml-namespaces

i am attempting to fix a data error within an XML file using the ElementTree module.
i was able to read in/ parse the file and fix the issue, but ran into an error with namespaces after writing the file

here is my code for registering the namespaces (which i ran prior to reading in/ parsing the file):

```
  ET.register_namespace('', 'http://example.com')                             #1
  ET.register_namespace('ns2', 'dsig:http://www.w3.org/example/xmldsig#')     #2
  ET.register_namespace('dsig', 'http://www.w3.org/example/xmldsig#')         #3
  ET.register_namespace('xsi', 'http://example.com/Schema/example')           #4
```

lines 1, 3, and 4 run without issue, but line 2 returns error: "ValueError: Prefix format reserved for internal use" due to the naming of prefix 2 being 'ns2'

my file requires keeping 'ns2' as the prefix and not registering this particular namespace causes me to lose it and a couple others in my heading after writing the new file

does anyone know how to resolve this issue??

Comment: Instead of trying to parse the SOAP message as if it was just another XML document, why not use a SOAP library? The namespaces you posted have well defined functionality and behavior. There's no reason to manually parse them from scratch.

Comment: The Python Wiki lists [several libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices#SOAP) for SOAP web services. There are several SO questions that ask how to parse SOAP messages as well

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589979/how-to-parse-soap-xml-in-python) is one of the [147 SO search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+parse+soap) returned when searching for `python parse soap`. It uses a simplified parser that ignores namespaces when possible

Comment: Line 2 is wrong. The name for digital signatures is `dsig`, not `ns2:dsig` or `ns2` with a URL that starts with `ns2:dsig`. In the [W3C example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-SOAP-dsig-20010206/#ex) the namespace is defined as `ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"`